# How to mock function with arguments spanning lines

Tags: python, mocking

I'm patching in my test (python2.7):

```
args[1].return_value.getMarkToMarketReportWithSummary.return_value = ([], {})
```

and I can see the

the expected mocked method with the correct return value when debugging:

[image]

and calling it is all good:

[image]

*But*, the method has multiple arguments:

```
rows, summary = manager.getMarkToMarketReportWithSummary(
    portfolios, report_data_map, account,
    ...
    include_twrr=self.__include_twrr)
```

and when the test runner calls the method it fails and returns a MagicMock instead of expected above. It's because of the arguments, making the method call a string or something. It looks like this:

[image]

so the method name looks the same but it has the `\n` with the args, etc. What is this? Is it an onion? Because it is making me cry.

Evaluating it a after that gives one more attribute, this time with `@LINE@`, because, you know, rubbing salt in my eyes is its goal:

[image]

:_(